# How to make if dependent HtmlHelper usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods, html-helper

Im using asp.net mvc 2.0. I have the following HtmlHelper extension:

```
AdminOnly(HtmlHelper helper, IPrincipal User, string htmlToRender)
{
   //Render Html if have admin access.
}
```

I need to modify it to use in such a way:
AdminOnly(User).TextBoxFor(x=>x.MyField)
So that it could render edit field for MyField only if user has admin access.

---

For now Ive come out with the following solution:

```
AdminOnly(this MvcHtmlString resString, IPrincipal User)
{
   //Render Html if have admin access.
}
```

So in code I can write things like:

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.MyProperty).AdminOnly(User)%>
```

It works but I would like to be able to add more inputs or more flexibility to add text before and after the inputs, like this:

```
<%:Html.PlainText("Set your age: ").TextBoxFor(x=>x.Age).AdminOnly(User)%>
```

or

```
<%: Html.AdminOnly("Set your age: ", User).AddTextBoxFor(x=>x.Age)%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you don't expect rendering stuff for other than current identity and you are using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` I'd recommend to leave out the `user` parameter and using `HttpContext.Current.User` or `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

2) Using chained method calls would probably require quite a bit of work, instead I recommend taking advantage of lambda expressions.

Extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AdminOnly(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<MvcHtmlString> action)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin"))
        return action();

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Usage:

```
<%: Html.AdminOnly(() => Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field)) %>
```

edit: updated for mvc 2

Comment: Thanks, Lukáš! Will try to port to MVC 2 and post here. Anyway my voteup is for you :-)